# Good library for date ranges & periods

Tags: datetime, calendar

This question is kind of a subset of [90308](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90308/what-languages-do-date-time-and-calendar-operations-really-well)

I'm looking for a good date library in any language which can handle periodic concepts

Date Ranges/sets which are independent of year:

```
  dr = 1 May - 31 August

  (4 May 2010) in dr
```

true

```
  (4 May 2011) in dr
```

true

```
  (4 March 2012) in dr
```

false

Day sets:

```
  ds = m tu w sa su

  (Mon, 4 May 2010) in ds
```

true

```
  (Thurs, 7 May 2010) in ds
```

false

Also nice set-like operations of the above such as intersection, union and inverse

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/325933/1025391

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with C++, you can use boost::date_time. See the example at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.date_period_calc

Comment: Looks interesting, unfortunately c++ is not an option productivity wise.